# Как в List<>точечно добраться в классах с геттерами-сеттерами до информации

Tags: java, android

Возможно я глупо сформулировал оглавление, но на ум более грамотное ничего не приходит. Короче поехали)
Есть следующий класс.

```
public class PjMain {
private List<PjMainData> data;

public List<PjMainData> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<PjMainData> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return data.toString();
}
```

Из него исходят следующий классы

```
public class PjMainData {
private PjMakeModel make,model;
private PjColor color;
private PjPrice price;


public PjMakeModel getMake() {
    return make;
}

public void setMake(PjMakeModel make) {
    this.make = make;
}

public PjMakeModel getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(PjMakeModel model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public PjColor getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(PjColor color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public PjPrice getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(PjPrice price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PjMainData{" +
            "make=" + make +
            ", model=" + model +
            ", color=" + color +
            ", price=" + price +
            '}';
}
```

Ну и для наглядности добавлю последний

```
public class PjPrice {
private String min,max;

public String getMin() {
    return min;
}

public void setMin(String min) {
    this.min = min;
}

public String getMax() {
    return max;
}

public void setMax(String max) {
    this.max = max;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PjPrice{" +
            "min='" + min + '\'' +
            ", max='" + max + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Возможно ли как-то точечно добраться до инфы в таком случае с помощью get методов, чтобы не загонять всё в массивы.
Например Из последнего класса нужно вытянуть строку max (код с ошибкой, чисто для понимания цепочки. и чего я хочу)
 `String price_max= pjMain.getData().toString()//.pjPrice.getMax()//;`

Имеется очень много информации, и разбирать их на каждый случай довольно затруднительно. Как правильно точечно вытягивать в таких случаях информацию, если это вообще возможно.

Comment: А вы с интерфейсом `List` знакомы? Там и кроется ответ на ваш вопрос. Метод `getData()` как раз его и возвращает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PJMain pjMain;
//blah-blah
for(PJMainData pjMainData:pjMain.getData()) {
   System.out.println("Max price="+pjMainData.getPrice().getMax());
}
```

Comment: человек просил точечно получать информацию

Answer (score 2):

Реализуйте паттерн Компоновщик, который ["определяет иерархию классов, которые одновременно могут состоять из примитивных и сложных объектов, упрощает архитектуру клиента, делает процесс добавления новых видов объекта более простым."](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Answer (score 0):

```
 PjMain.getData().get(position1).getModel().getColor().НазваНужногоМетода()
 PjMain.getData().get(position1).getModel().getPrice().getMax()
```

примерно так. студия подскажет какие методы доступны